# Chrono high_resolution_clock giving inconsistent times?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

So I have a program that evaluates a polynomial in two different ways: Honrer's method and a Naive method. I'm trying to see their run times respectively, but depending on which order I place the function calls their times change. For example, I place the Horner method first and it takes longer. I then tried with the naive method first and then it takes longer. The Horner method should be much much faster since it only has one loop where the naive method has a nested loop. So i figured it must be the way I'm using the clocks from the chrono library. I tried both the high_resolution_clock and system_clock, but the same thing happens. Any help/comments are welcomed.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include "Polynomial.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  double c[5] = {5, 0, -3, 1, -8};
  int degree = 4;
  Polynomial obj(c, degree);

  auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  std::cout<<"Horner Evaluation: " << obj.hornerEval(-2)<<",  ";

  auto elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
  auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(elapsed).count();
  std::cout<< duration << " nanoseconds "<<std::endl;


  auto start2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  std::cout<<"Naive Evaluation: " << obj.naiveEval(-2)<<", ";

  auto elapsed2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start2;
  auto duration2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(elapsed2).count();

  std::cout<< duration2 << " nanoseconds "<<std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: I would rather suspect `std::cout` taking a significant amount of time. You should not include the I/O time in your measurements.

Comment: 1) make sure you have optimizations enabled. 2) run each benchmark a few thousand times. 3) make sure you don't include stdio times in your benchmark.

Comment: I believe that did it... with i/o taken out they both run much faster. Thanks.

Comment: Also for timings I generally use `std::chrono::steady_clock`

Comment: Computers are very very very very very very complicated. Seems you have forgotten to factor that in! We are not working on mechanical machines with punch cards any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't put all the code but from description it looks it is caching effect.
When it runs first method CPU cache is cold (data from memory is not yet populated with CPU cache) so it takes more time to process (memory is slow compared to cache).
When second method is called it has all (or most depending on data size) the data already available in cache - cache is hot.

Solution - call both methods outside timing part first to warm up the cache than do measurements.

Comment: Typically you should run it at least thousands of times and throw out the first hundred or so to get a real measure

Comment: In this case it will work but it is not universal solution - it will show same "method call time dependency" effect if every round refers to different memory address.

Comment: That's what I thought might be happening but I'm not savvy enough yet to put it into technical terms haha. And yeah I believe my prof said something along those lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like one of the previous responds already said, it's probably something with the cache, the prefetcher can maybe better determine which memory to load into cache in the naiveEval method. Here is a talk about benchmarking c++ code for futher information for exapmle on the effect of cold starts on benchmarking: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWxSZcpeS8Q

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks!